# how to enumerate MVC 5 viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Seems like viewbag is an instance of System.Web.Mvc.DynamicViewDataDictionary. Which is internal and so I cant cast ViewBag to it. And that type doesn't expose an IDictionary interface (cf ExpandoObject)

So how can I do this

```
foreach(var kv in <ViewBag magic>)
{
   .....
}
```

I see that System.Web.Mvc.DynamicViewDataDictionary has a Keys method but that doesn't help since I cannot get a dynamic object value dynamically. ie I cant do

```
var k = "Key1";
var v = ViewBag[k];
```

Comment: what use case would you have that would require you to do this?

Comment: I want to copy the viewbag to a different dictionary type object. I know I could refactor the code (or just write a large set of assignments one for each property) but the ViewBag generating code is large and dispersed - and I am lazy

Comment: The other reason to do this is on the OnActionExecuting method on a controller, you could override it to synchronize the values in TempData and ViewBag.  Which is how I got here in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewData` property -- a [`ViewDataDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) -- will contain the same data as `ViewBag` (`ViewBag` is basically a wrapper around `ViewData`).

A `ViewDataDictionary` is a structure that can be iterated (it implements `IDictionary<string, object>` and various `IEnumerable`s):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in ViewData)
{

}
```

There are ways to cast `ExpandoObject`s to `IDictionary<string, object>`s but you're basically still in the same boat, since you will need to know what types you're working with to cast them from `object` to something useful.

Comment: cool - I hadnt realized that ViewData and ViewBag were backed by the same store

Answer (score 1):

The ViewBag acts as a wrapper on ViewData. **You can use reflection to enumerate the properties of a ViewBag**.

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = ViewBag.GetType().GetProperty("ViewData",
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

var viewDataDictionary = pInfo.GetValue(ViewBag, null);
```

The resulting dictionary will have a set of Keys and Values that can be enumerated.

**Note:** The ViewData property being reflected here is a Non Public member and you may want to decide between using a ViewBag and ViewData which directly permits enumeration.